# Elasticsearch "observer: timeout notification from cluster service" debug message

Tags: elasticsearch

We have had a cluster with two nodes (running ES version 1.5.2), all within the same subnet, and recently added a third.  When we added the third node, the master node started logging this message every 30s:

```
[2016-03-10 16:34:25,584][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.health] [<master-node>] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
```

The cluster health is green, and all nodes are connected. Everything seems fine except for that debug message.

Our config settings in each node are identical except node name:

```
cluster.name: "tmes"
node.name: "tmes1.<subnet>"
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 3s
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["tmes1:9300", "tmes2:9300", "tmes3:9300"]
```

Has anyone come across this before? Or see what we are doing wrong?

I've seen other people talking about this message, but most seem to have the cluster not connecting at all, or the message only happening intermittently.

Thanks!
Isabel

Comment: There are many reasons why this could have started (out of disk space, etc) . You should check whether any of the [reported issues](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/search?q=%22timeout+notification+from+cluster+service%22&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)  with this debug message are similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks Val.  Yeah I had a look, but don't see anyone with quite the same problem.  As I said before, most seem to have the cluster not connecting at all, or the message only happening intermittently.  So that makes me wonder whether we've configured the cluster wrong.